# как сделать, чтобы данные после окончания функции стирались с окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Недавно начал изучать tkinter, столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть список и кнопка, при нажатии на кнопку считывается значение списка и выводится информация на экран. Как сделать так, чтобы после выбора другого значения из списка прошлая информация стиралась?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()
window.title("Student Geometry Helper")
window.geometry("500x500")


def clickedCombobox():
    global FigureResult
    FigureResult = ChooseFigureList.get()
    if FigureResult == "Квадрат":


        action_one = Label(window,text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two = Label(window, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))

        action_one = Label(window,text="Площадь равна квадрату стороны                                                                                  ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_one.place(x=10,y=180)

        action_two = Label(window, text="Площадь равна частному квадрата диагонали и двух                                                            ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two.place(x=10,y=210)

        if clickedCombobox == True:
            action_one.configure(text="")
            action_two.configure(text="")



    elif FigureResult == "Прямоугольник":


        action_one = Label(window,text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two = Label(window, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))

        action_one = Label(window,text="Площадь равна произведению двух сторон                                                                                          ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_one.place(x=10,y=180)

        action_two = Label(window, text="Площадь равна произведению периметра и стороны вычесть удвоенную степень этой стороны и делить на 2                                                  ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two.place(x=10,y=210)

        if clickedCombobox == True:
            action_one.configure(text="")
            action_two.configure(text="")

    elif FigureResult == "Треугольник":

        action_one = Label(window,text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two = Label(window, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))

        action_one = Label(window,text="Площадь равна половине произведения двух сторон и синуса угла этих двух сторон                                                            ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_one.place(x=10,y=180)

        action_two = Label(window, text="Площадь равна половине произведения стороны и высоты к этой стороне                                                                      ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two.place(x=10,y=210)

        if clickedCombobox == True:
            action_one.configure(text="")
            action_two.configure(text="")

    elif FigureResult == "Круг":
        action_one = Label(window,text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two = Label(window, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))

        action_one.configure(text="")
        action_two.configure(text="")

        action_one = Label(window,text="Площадь равна произведению радиуса и квадрата числа ПИ                                ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_one.place(x=10,y=180)

        action_two = Label(window, text="Площадь равна произведению квадрата диаметра на число ПИ, деленое на 2                                          ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
        action_two.place(x=10,y=210)

        round_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Screenshot_1.png"))
        round_label = Label(image=round_img)
        round_label.place(x=10,y=246)
        round_label.mainloop()


MainLabel = Label(window,text="Student Geometry Helper v0.1", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
MainLabel.pack()

ChooseFigure = Label(window, text="Выберете фигуру:", font=("Arial Bold", 16))
ChooseFigure.place(x=10,y=70)

ChooseFigureList = Combobox(window)
ChooseFigureList['values'] = ('Квадрат','Прямоугольник','Треугольник','Круг')
ChooseFigureList.current(0)
ChooseFigureList.place(x=10,y=110)

btnDone = Button(window, text="Готово",command=clickedCombobox)
btnDone.place(x=10,y=145)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Создавайте `action_one`, `action_two`, `round_label` не каждый раз при нажатии кнопки, а один раз глобально при старте программы, а внутри `clickedCombobox` просто заменяйте их содержимое.
2. Чтобы при переключении комбо выполнялось какое-то действие, нужно привязать какую-то функцию к событию `<<ComboboxSelected>>`, в этой функции меняете содержимое меток `action_one`, `action_two`, `round_label` на пустое.
3. Чтобы картинка отображалась, картинку нужно записать в глобальную переменную, или в поле какого-то объекта (который тоже должен быть в какой-то глобальной переменной). Если она будет только внутри локальной переменной, то сборщик мусора удалит ее сразу после выхода из функции. Можно при старте программы загрузить все картинки в отдельные переменные или в список, а внутри функций просто подставлять нужную картинку.

Код с исправлениями:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()
window.title("Student Geometry Helper")
window.geometry("500x500")


def clickedCombobox():
    FigureResult = ChooseFigureList.get()
    if FigureResult == "Квадрат":
        action_one['text'] = "Площадь равна квадрату стороны"
        action_two['text'] = "Площадь равна частному квадрата диагонали и двух"

    elif FigureResult == "Прямоугольник":
        action_one['text'] = "Площадь равна произведению двух сторон"
        action_two['text'] ="Площадь равна произведению периметра и стороны вычесть удвоенную степень этой стороны и делить на 2"

    elif FigureResult == "Треугольник":
        action_one['text'] = "Площадь равна половине произведения двух сторон и синуса угла этих двух сторон"
        action_two['text'] = "Площадь равна половине произведения стороны и высоты к этой стороне"

    elif FigureResult == "Круг":
        action_one['text'] = "Площадь равна произведению радиуса и квадрата числа ПИ"
        action_two['text'] = "Площадь равна произведению квадрата диаметра на число ПИ, деленое на 2"
        image_label["image"] = round_img


def combo_select(_event):
    action_one['text'] = ""
    action_two['text'] = ""
    image_label["image"] = None


round_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Screenshot_1.png"))


MainLabel = Label(window,text="Student Geometry Helper v0.1", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
MainLabel.pack()

action_one = Label(window,text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
action_one.place(x=10,y=180)
action_two = Label(window, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
action_two.place(x=10,y=210)
image_label = Label()
image_label.place(x=10,y=246)

ChooseFigure = Label(window, text="Выберете фигуру:", font=("Arial Bold", 16))
ChooseFigure.place(x=10,y=70)

ChooseFigureList = Combobox(window)
ChooseFigureList['values'] = ('Квадрат','Прямоугольник','Треугольник','Круг')
ChooseFigureList.current(0)
ChooseFigureList.place(x=10,y=110)
ChooseFigureList.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_select)

btnDone = Button(window, text="Готово",command=clickedCombobox)
btnDone.place(x=10,y=145)

window.mainloop()
```